# Не смог предотвратить что-то или чего-то?

Tags: падежи, родительный-или-винительный

Как правильно? Винительный или родительный падеж?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Не смог предотвратить что-то или чего-то?" Как правильно? Винительный
>   или родительный падеж?

По грамматическим причинам предпочтителен винительный. ***Не смог предотвратить катастрофу,*** например.
Здесь отрицание идет не при управляющем глаголе, а при модальном, т. е. управление "предотвратить катастрофу". От него и надо отталкиваться.

В современном языке, правда, отрицание при модальном глаголе может иногда оказывать влияние на выбор управления, но это больше относится к разговорному стилю - и влияние это заметно слабее того, что возникает при отрицании глагола смыслового. К тому же, есть подозрение, что мотивы выбора падежа при такой ситуации сильно отличаются от того, что было бы в случае непосредственного отрицания глагола. Разговоров о категоричности или ослабленности высказывания здесь быть не должно, на первое место выступает мотив конкретности.
Вот сравните.
*"Не могу написать письмо"* - конкретное письмо.
*"Не могу написать письма"* - вообще никакого не могу.
Нечто подобное имеет место и в нашем случае. 
*"Не смог предотвратить катастрофу"* - обычная форма, речь о конкретной катастрофе.
*"Не смог (бы) предотвратить катастрофы"* - разговорный вариант, мог бы применяться по отношению к какой-то гипотетической ситуации неясного характера.

По семантике всего высказывания второй вариант маловероятен, разве что в сослагательном наклонении.
Итак, по все параметрам: винительный предпочтителен.

**UPD**

> Мне кажется, вы с Sibyll-ой противоречите друг другу насчёт книжного и разговорного стиля одновременно в случае с родительным падежом...

Мне не только это кажется. "Противоречия" у нас прежде всего в подходе. Я не вижу тут возможности напрямую применять соображения о падеже дополнения при отрицании  глагола, поскольку отрицание идет у глагола модального. А это меняет дело, падежом у нас управляет глагол без отрицания. В подтверждение могу привести ответ Пушкина по своим критикам, стоящим на той же позиции, что и Sibilla, и требовавшим родительного падежа.

> Стих:
>
> Два века ссорить не хочу
>
> критику показался неправильным. Что гласит грамматика? Что
>   действительный глагол, управляемый отрицательною частицею, требует уже
>   не винительного, а родительного падежа. Например: я не пишу стихов. Но
>   в моем стихе глагол ссорить управляем не частицею не, а глаголом хочу.
>   Ergo {2} правило сюда нейдет. Возьмем, например, следующее
>   предложение: Я не могу вам позволить начать писать... стихи, а уж
>   конечно не стихов. Неужто электрическая сила отрицательной частицы
>   должна пройти сквозь всю эту цепь глаголов и отозваться в
>   существительном? Не думаю.

(из статьи «Опровержение на критики», 1830; орфография - современная).

Этот кусок часто цитируется как раз в плоскости наших разговоров, найдете при желании.

> ...но не думаю, что независимо от этого предпочтителен какой-либо из вариантов.

Если бы речь шла об отрицании основного глагола, я бы еще согласился. Но тут предпочтительность предопределяет грамматика, а не семантика, о чем писал, пишу и буду писать.

Comment: Спасибо, behemothus!

Comment: Мне кажется, вы с Sibyll-ой противоречите друг другу насчёт книжного и разговорного стиля одновременно в случае с родительным падежом... Интересно, как всё-таки на самом деле.

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что мотив выбора связан прежде всего с конкретностью, но не думаю, что независимо от этого предпочтителен какой-либо из вариантов. Возможны случаи, когда родительный падеж естественнее (бог рог не даёт, он же "не дал таланта" и т. п.). С разговорностью связь весьма смутная.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *Мне кажется, вы с Sibyll-ой противоречите друг другу* - мне это не только кажется. Подробности сейчас в тексте ответа дам.

Comment: @Alex_ander и вас прошу мой ответ посмотреть.

Comment: Да, Александр, тут речь не обо всех случаях, а об этом, где два глагола.

Comment: @behemothus, а что вы думаете по поводу следующего фрагмента из "Бриллиантовой руки"? — ...Пистолет и деньги я получил для выполнения ответственного спецзадания. — Какого? — Это**го** я тебе не могу сказать...

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - да ничего особенного. Опять-таки разговорный вариант, становящийся постепенно все более и более нормативным... Но тут еще и местоимение, а они в этих вопросах всегда бегут впереди паровоза.

Answer (score 0):

Это тема **выбора падежа дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием.** В этом случае возможны оба варианта, но следует учитывать общую характеристику падежа, а также  влияние различных факторов.

**Родительный падеж:** подчеркнутое (строгое)  отрицание, книжная речь. **Винительный падеж**: ослабленное отрицание, разговорная речь.

Когда пилоты проехали 232 круга из положенных 251, даже окрик шефа команды, раздавшийся в наушниках обоих пилотов, **не смог предотвратить катастрофы**. Его признали виновным  в том, что он **не смог предотвратить нападения** боевиков на лагеря  беженцев.

Как мы видим, в данных примерах выбран Р. п. (не смог предотвратить - книжный стиль).

Но: Старик **не мог простить** сыну его **свадьбу**. Он **не смог сдержать улыбку**. Он **не решался сообщить** матери **правду**.  Считается, что в этих случаях (как и в заданном примере) **отрицание ослаблено**, так как частица НЕ относится к модальному глаголу, и поэтому используется В. п. Стиль нейтральный.

Таким образом, в заданном примере оба варианта будут правильными.

Comment: Спасибо, Sibylla!